# A Particular Interaction Matrix in a Fully Connected Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, ising-model

I’m considering a fully connected Ising model with a Hamiltonian of the form:

$$ H = \sum_{i<j} J_{ij} S_i S_j $$

where $S_i = \pm 1$ represents the spin of each particle, and the sum is over all pairs of particles. The interaction matrix $J_{ij}$ is given by

$$J_{ij} = (i + j)(1 - \delta_{ij}) $$

which means that the interaction strength between any two spins depends on the sum of their indices.

This seems to represent a system where the interaction strength between two particles increases linearly with their distance on the lattice. However, I’m having trouble finding real-world systems that could potentially be described by this model.

Could anyone provide examples of real-world systems (e.g., in condensed matter physics, statistical mechanics, etc.) that might be described by such a model? Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reference of the model?

Comment: I wish there was. Unfortunately, I've come up with this. I'm asking because I've found an exact solution for the ground state energy and also its corresponding configuration. So, I wanted to know if this is trivial for the community or not, and whether a real system like this exists.  @TobiasFünke

Comment: What is the range of the indices? Symmetric about $0$ or only positive?

Comment: @LPZ it is $1 \le i < j \le N$. By inspection, you can clearly see that the matrix is symmetric with main diagonal being zero.

Comment: It's uncommon to see interactions increase with distance in real physical systems, outside of confining potentials in quantum systems (I'm not personally aware of classical examples of confinement). You could still write it up as a paper though if you have a solution, but you'd want to investigate its properties, etc. People come up with soluble toy models all the time, and who knows maybe someone will find a physical application!

Comment: @justaphase actually we are writing it as a paper. As a matter of fact, this interaction matrix and its solution is part of a more general class!

Comment: Nice! And identifying a more general class is great! If you see an analogue of confinement I would recommend discussing it too :)